# MySQL request count from many tables

Tags: mysql, count, request

I have tables `table_one, table_two, table_three, table_four` all structure is about same.
it has columns `id, name, status, user_id`.

i.g. i have user John with `user_id 345` in every table multiple times except table_four. and `status` for some entrys is 1 and other entry's is 0

Now i need to count with one query how many times status for this user was 1 in each of this tables.

So i do:

```
SELECT table_one.user_id,
   SUM(CASE WHEN table_one.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_tblone
   SUM(CASE WHEN table_two.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_tbltwo
   SUM(CASE WHEN table_three.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_tblthree
   SUM(CASE WHEN table_four.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_tblfour
FROM table_one
   LEFT JOIN table_one   ON table_one.user_id   = table_one.user_id
   LEFT JOIN table_two   ON table_two.user_id   = table_one.user_id
   LEFT JOIN table_three ON table_three.user_id = table_one.user_id
   LEFT JOIN table_four  ON table_four.user_id  = table_one.user_id

WHERE tbl_one.user_id = 345
```

Problem is that request outputs 4, 0, 0, 0 when it should be 2, 1, 1, 0

IF i just leave `SUM(CASE WHEN table_one.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_tblone` - `count_tblone` will equal 4 even if in `table_one` - `status` field equals 1 in only two records for user `345`.

Comment: What isn't working? Also: did you mean to use `= tbl_resume.candidate_id` in the `LEFT JOIN`s?

Comment: Each of the tables is joining to itself on its own key which does not  make sense. My thinking is you are left joining from table_one to table_two, table_two to table_three, table_three to table_four. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @JohnA Please post your fix as an answer in case anyone else comes along and has the same problem :)

Comment: Ok ok i fixed it...  sorry guys. can someone answer now?

Comment: Are you still looking for more answers to this question? Or have you solved it in another way you can share with the community?

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot more typing, but I'd recommend UNION, **especially if user might not be in table_one**.

```
SELECT
   SUM(count_tblone) AS count_tblone,
   SUM(count_tbltwo) AS count_tbltwo,
   SUM(count_tblthree) AS count_tblthree,
   SUM(count_tblfour) AS count_tblfour
FROM (
   SELECT 
      SUM(CASE WHEN table_one.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_tblone,
      0 AS count_tbltwo,
      0 AS count_tblthree,
      0 AS count_tblfour
   FROM table_one
   WHERE tbl_one.user_id = 345
   UNION
   SELECT 
      0 AS count_tblone,
      SUM(CASE WHEN table_two.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_tbltwo,
      0 AS count_tblthree,
      0 AS count_tblfour
   FROM table_two
   WHERE tbl_one.user_id = 345
   UNION
```

... tables 3 and 4 ...

```
) AS tblMyUnionedTables
```

Comment: Additionally, if it's fine to retrieve your results as 4 one-column rows, instead of 1 four-column row, then you can take out the `0 AS count_tbl...` items, and you can just get the results from what is now a sub-table in the answer above. Note that in that case you will need `UNION ALL` in place of `UNION`. Also in that case, you could add `status = 1` within the where clause and just get counts.